# How to change font color from red to green in if statement

Tags: php, html, css

I got a table row which contains an id which is below:

```
  <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
```

In the css page, the `#errormsg' id turns the text color to red as shown below in the seperate css file:

```
#errormsg{
    color:red;  
}
```

But I have a little situation. I have an if statement here:

```
if(mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)){
$errormsg = "You have been Registered. You must Activate your Account from the Activation Link sent to <b>$getemail</b>";
                                                }
```

Now what I want to happen is that if this if statement is met, I want the $errormsg to change the font color from red to green. Is this actually possible?

Comment: [Don't use tables for layout](http://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t+use+tables+for+layout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  $errormsg = "<span style='color: green'>You have been Registered. You must Activate your Account from the Activation Link sent to <b>$getemail</b></span>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$color = "red";

if(mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    $color = "green";
    $errormsg = "You have been Registered. You must Activate your Account from the Activation Link sent to <b>$getemail</b>";
}
....
echo "<td style='color:$color;' id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>";
```

Comment: And you get a nice parse error, for mixing PHP and HTML code together.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$extraErrorClass = '';
if(mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    $errormsg = "You have been Registered. You must Activate your Account from the Activation Link sent to <b>$getemail</b>";
    $extraErrorClass = ' class="error-green"';
}

echo "<td id='errormsg'$extraErrorClass>$errormsg</td>";
?>
```

Or perhaps better readable:

```
echo '<td id="errormsg"', $extraErrorClass, '>', $errormsg, '</td>';
```

And just add the extra class to your CSS:

```
#errormsg.error-green {
    color: green;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

**PHP:**

```php
<?php
// ...
$result = mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($result) {
?>
<div class="message message-success">You have been registered. Please activate your account from the activation link sent to <strong><?php echo $getemail; ?></strong>.
<?php
} else {
?>
<div class="message message-fail">Sorry, an error occurred when sending the activation email to <strong><?php echo $getemail; ?></strong>.
<?php
}
// ...
?>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.message {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888
}
.message-success {
    background: #afa;
    color: #040
}
.message-fail {
    background: #faa;
    color: #400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#errormsg{
    color:red;  
}

#okmsg{
    color:green;  
}
```

```php
  $status = "errormsg";
  if(mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    $msg = "You have been Registered. You must Activate your Account from the Activation Link sent to <b>$getemail</b>";
    $status = "okmsg";
  }
```

```php
<td id="$status">$msg</td>
```

Comment: `<td id="$status"><?php echo $msg; ?></td>`